# How to write shell script on website login

Tags: bash, shell, curl, scripting, sh

I already written shell script but its exactly not working getting empty response it should first return token and also it should login then registry API

thats my task of shell script has to do

```
#!/bin/bash
# Begin

TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "base_url:,auth0_url:,register_url:,username:,password:,openapi_spec:,base_path:,label:,test_email:" -- -- "$@")

[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

eval set -- "$TEMP"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        --base_url) BASE_URL="$2"; shift ;;
        --auth0_url) AUTH0_URL="$2"; shift ;;
        --register_url) REGISTER_URL="$2"; shift ;;
        --username) TEST_USER="$2"; shift ;;
        --password) TEST_PWD="$2"; shift ;;
        --openapi_spec) OPENAPI_SPEC="$2"; shift ;;
        --base_path) BASEPATH_SPEC="$2"; shift ;;
        --label) LABEL="$2"; shift ;;
        --test_email) TEST_EMAIL="$2"; shift ;;
        --) shift ;;
    esac
    shift
done

# Set defaults for configurable options
BASE_URL=${BASE_URL:-"https://dev.cloudnetwork.in"}
AUTH0_URL=${AUTH0_URL:-"https://dev-yxxxxxxx1.us.auth0.com"}
REGISTER_URL=${REGISTER_URL:-"https://dev.cloudnetwork.in/apis/register"}


#f [ "$BASE_URL" = "" ];
#then
#    BASE_URL="https://dev.cloudnetwork.in"
#fi


echo " "
token=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${TEST_USER}'", "password": "'${TEST_PWD}'"}'  ${AUTH0_URL}/login ${BASE_URL}/login ${REGISTER_URL}/login | jq -r .token)

echo "generated token is:" $token

echo " "

data=$(curl -k -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --location --request POST "https://dev.cloudnetwork.in/api/v1/api/test" --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" -d  '{"base_url":"'"${BASE_URL}"'","auth0_url":"'"${AUTH0_URL}"'","register_url":"'"${REGISTER_URL}"'","openapi_spec":"'"${OPENAPI_SPEC}"'","base_path":"'"${BASEPATH_SPEC}"'","label":"'"${LABEL}"'","test_email":"'"${TEST_EMAIL}"'"}' | jq -r .token)

label_name=$(jq -r '.label')
created_email=$(jq -r '.created_by_email')

echo "Successfully created the API Register."
echo "LabelName: $label_name"
echo "CreatedEmail: $created_email"
echo 'Script Execution is Done.'
echo "Successfully created $NoProjectsToCreate projects in $TEST_HOSTNAME environment!!!"
```

Here is my output command

```
./dev-registry.sh --base_url "https://dev.cloudnetwork.in" --auth0_url "https://dev-yxxxxxxxx1.us.auth0.com" --register_url "https://dev.cloudnetwork.in/apis/register" --username "test@cloudnetwork.in" --password "123456" --openapi_spec "https://xxxxxx.yaml" --base_path "https://xxxxxxx/v2" --label "Demo" --test_email "test@cloudnetwork.in"
```

Here is my website login browser response which below shows all details from here i take and add into shell script inside curl

```
 {
    BASE_URL: 'https://dev.cloudnetwork.in',
    AUTH0_URL: 'https://dev-yxxxxxxxxx1.us.auth0.com',
    USERNAME: 'test@cloudnetwork.in',
    PASSWORD: '123456',
    REGISTER_URL:'https://dev.cloudnetwork.in/apis/register',
  },


1. GENERAL
Request URL:     https://dev.cloudnetwork.in/api/v1/api/test
Request Method:  POST

2. Request Header
authority:       api.dev.cloudnetwork.in
method:          POST
path:            /api/v1/api/test
Authorization:   Bearer
eyJhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxeaLvIBUOsH6gGQ1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0huyw

3. Payload
openapi_spec:      "https://xxxxx/xxxxx.yaml"
base_path:          "https://xxxxxxx/v2"
test_email:   "test@cloudnetwork.in"
label:              "demo"

{"openapi_spec":"https://xxxxxxxx.yaml","base_path":"https://xxxxxxxx/v2","label":"demossss"}
```

So, using above details im pulling token, login and registering an API the same i want to do from shell script above is script but its return empty response

i dont know where im wrong

Comment: Which of those responses is empty? You have two `curl` calls in  your script, so you have two responses.

Comment: first one token=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${TEST_USER}'", "password": "'${TEST_PWD}'"}'

Comment: Does it work on the command line, with the exact same settings for the shell variables?

Comment: yes null it return

Comment: can u tell me how to add single page signing using curl method

Comment: If it does not work on the command line either, the problem is not your script, but the invocation of curl. In this case, the question is not about programming, but on the use of a certain command. It is completely unnecessary to post the script. The command alone is sufficient. Stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask about the usage of commands. May I suggest that you post it on [su] instead?

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)